# Blender crashes after several hours of animation rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hardware

TL;DR Blender crashes after several hours of cycles animation rendering, why, have old hardware, need new PC anyway, want components that zucc the issue away.

So I have a rather complex scene in cycles with heaps of reflections, refractions, transparencies, light sources and like 2 3K textures and I'm rendering it all in a 500 frame animation. It's taking approximately 2-3 days with my hardware on the saple rate, lightbounces etc. But the problem arises when I get back home/wake up to see that render had crashed and maybe 2-3 hours of rendering was lost. It's no big deal because I can just continue the render right where it stopped.

But what I'm wondering is why this is, I'm assuming at this point it's just my old hardware, too much RAM useage/VRAM useage because sometimes when blender crashes I see some kinda error to do with the gpu or memory (I'll try get the actual error code if there is one) but more often than not blender just closes quietly with no error.

I'm wondering this because I am in big need of a new computer anyway and if I was to get a new one what kind of upgrades would I specifically be looking at to directly crush this issue because it'd be great to just start a nice phat render going over a week while I'm holidays for example.

PC Specs:

Cpu: i7-3770 3.40GHz 4 cores 8 threads
RAM: 16GB 1600MHz RAM
Gpu1: Gigabyte Geforce GTX 1650 4GB VRAM
Gpu2: ASUS GeForce GTX 1050ti 4GB VRAM
Mobo: Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3H
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: "maybe 2-3 hours of rendering was lost." This can't happen if you render animation to .png.  You'll get a image sequence that can't be 'lost' if blender crashes.  Blender can later create a movie (quickly) out of the image sequence under video editing.

Comment: Hello :). One of many possible reasons - your render tiles might be too big. This causes Blender crash without any warning. Scale them down just a bit, and see if it helps. Works for me, but might not work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback mates, very appreciated. What I meant, Mike, with "maybe 2-3 hours of rendering" being lost was that the render crashed and 2-3 hours later I found out so that's 2-3 hours it could have been rendering. I have been rendering in PNG and it's beautiful and is why I'm not so fussed with the render crashing. Thanks boys.